# Vertex which is present in all Minimum Dominating Sets for Bipartite graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, np-hard

I am working on Minimum Dominating sets for bipartite graphs. There can be many minimum dominating sets of same size and I want vertex which is present in all of them. My approach for generating dominating sets is try all subsets of vertex and check if it is minimum dominating sets and then take the intersection of all the sets(this will give such vertex). Any clever way for doing this?

Comment: There might not be any vertex that is present in all minimum dominating sets.  What do you want to do in that case?  Are you aware that finding even a single minimum dominating set is NP-hard?  As a result you shouldn't expect any efficient algorithm for this problem.

Comment: I am aware that it is NP hard problem. But aren't there any property of bipartite graph which we can use to do it ?

Comment: Hint: Vertex cover is a closely related problem.  Look for an example of a bipartite graph that has a minimum vertex cover that is not simultaneously a minimum dominating set, and vice versa.  (And if you can't find any...?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker...Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, but I can repeat: Try looking for a bipartite graph that has a minimum vertex cover that is not simultaneously a minimum dominating set.  If after a while you can't find any, what should you attempt to do next?

Comment: I wrote a code and generated minimum dominating set and I could observe that it consists of vertex which have maximum degree and cover all graph. Is it correct observation or is there any counter example?